# kinit worked but without kinit ssh doesn't work.

Tags: ssh, freebsd, kerberos

```
Case 1) 
machine: kinit
machine: xxx@production.xxx.com's password: (inputted my password)
machine: ssh machineB
production.xxx.com
Successfully sshd. 

Case 2) 
machine: ssh machineB
production.xxx.com
password: (input the same pw)

password not right. ssh failed. logs says AM: authentication error for xxx from x.x.x.x
```

what does this tells me about the machine? i am confused.

Answer (score 0):

The machine is probably set up to require more authentication methods to succeed before you are authenticated. The option is called `AuthenticationMethods` and is described in `sshd_config(5)` manual page.

From the behaviour I guess there is value like `AuthenticationMethods password,gssapi`. If you are using some new version of openssh, there will be even note about partial failure.